# List<IGroup> custom sort c#

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, repeater

I am trying to render a search results page in tabbed layout (with categories as tabs). How can I make sure the tab order to be Products, Articles and Videos? Right now it always prints alphabetical (coz of orderby method I suppose). I am quite new to creating custom sorts/comparison. Thank you!

```
protected void ResultsRedendering(List<Item> searchResult)
    {
        _searchResults = searchResult.GroupBy(i => i.TemplateName).OrderBy(p=>p.Key).ToList();
        _searchResults.RemoveAll(i => i.Key != "Product" && i.Key != "Article" && i.Key != "Video");
        rptResultTab.DataSource = _searchResults;
        rptResultTab.DataBind();
    }
```

This is how my item template renders each tab...

```
<ItemTemplate>
            <li><a href="#<%#((IGrouping<string , Item>)Container.DataItem).Key %>">
                <%#((IGrouping<string, Item>)Container.DataItem).Key)%></a></li>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Also, _searchResult is of type `List<IGrouping<string,Item>>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while maybe not 100% optimal this should work.

```
 protected void ResultsRedendering(List<Item> searchResult)
            {
                var _searchResults = searchResult
                 .OrderBy(o => o.Key == "Product" ? 1 : o.Key== "Article" ? 2 : 3});
                var rptResultTab.DataSource = _searchResults;
                rptResultTab.DataBind();
            }
```

Comment: Hi Rob, the _searchResult object is of type List<IGrouping<string,Item>> and its complaining when I try to use your logic. Also if I cast it to List<IGrouping<string,Item>>, it blows up at runtime complaining it could not cast.

Comment: your answer gave me direction to get it working... thank you... this is what I did finally... <code>_searchResults = searchResult.GroupBy(i => i.TemplateName).OrderBy(o => o.Key == "Product" ? 1 : o.Key == "Article" ? 2 : 3).ToList();</code>

Answer (score 1):

You can make separate lists of the categories to make them a little easier to work with:

```
var products = searchResult.Where(sr => sr.Key == "Product");
var articles = searchResult.Where(sr => sr.Key == "Article");
var videos = searchResult.Where(sr => sr.Key == "Video");
```

It's unclear to me how you have your DataBinding setup exactly, so this is all I can really recommend right now.  If you add some more information I might be able to help further.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting this, I just edited my question with more details. Wondering if there is any other way out other than creating 3 different collections.